# Unable To Start Gitlab Runner Despite Installing

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-runner

I installed gitlab-runner on my computer which has windows 10 os.
But when i want to start runner then i get the error which is detailed below.
Have you ever encountered the following error ?
Thanks for your advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to `register` the runner to a project?

the wizard will take you through some base configuration for the runner, then you can start it.